# How to generate a unique integer id for string?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, uniqueidentifier

I have a list of long length strings, which should compare to each others repeatedly. What I'm looking for, is a way to generate unique integer value based of value of a string, which has minimum RAM/CPU usage, and can be fully trusted. Generating value for same strings, should always return same value. I know there is a lot of algorithms based on some hashing/encrypting mechanism, but they use a lot of resources, and they are not fast enough. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Igor oh please no, don't recommend that here; that's not what `GetHashCode()` does or means

Comment: The big problem you could have here is: what you're after isn't really a hash - it sounds like it needs to be more reliable than even a cryptographic hash (collisions still occur with crypto hashes). You're also going to have a huge problem if you need more than 4 billion (ish) strings, because: that's how many `int` values you have. What you'd essentially need here is: a large database of string lookups.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/386424). What is your end goal? Why are you trying to do this? (*what do you mean by "which should compare to each others repeatedly", sharing your existing implementation or something close to it would also be helpful*)

Comment: Obviously, only the strings themselves are totally unique values - any reduction to an integer is going to have collisions. What percentage of collisions are acceptable? Could you handle like hash tables and validate match after collision?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use some sort of check Sum functions that process strings and make a unique number for each specific string there is a function that I use in a large scale project for my self, I hope it can helps

```
private string GetChecksum(string text)
        {
            long sum = 0;
            byte overflow;
            for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
            {
                sum = (long)((16 * sum) ^ Convert.ToUInt32(text[i]));
                overflow = (byte)(sum / 4294967296);
                sum = sum - overflow * 4294967296;
                sum = sum ^ overflow;
            }

            if (sum > 2147483647)
                sum = sum - 4294967296;
            else if (sum >= 32768 && sum <= 65535)
                sum = sum - 65536;
            else if (sum >= 128 && sum <= 255)
                sum = sum - 256;

            sum = Math.Abs(sum);

            return sum.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. Seems fast. Did you used it for a lot of strings? I need it to be unique

Comment: it gives duplicates, for example this hash 1852554336 give both GUIDs 949520df-9cf5-4ca6-ab14-a12027319a07 and 20b4b2ba-a4f2-4f0c-b7aa-2031505c598d